# Reason why odoo 9 is very slow with a very less data

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

I am hosting odoo in local server and its very slow with 8 users. The website is slower then internal contents. I don't have large images or external scripts. here are it's specification .
Core 2 quad 3.2 
8GB of Ram
256GB SSD

I have check the logs there were no errors and the only thing i notice the system get slow when it reach to below lines. (openerp-server.log).

```
2016-08-09 16:29:41,084 5512 INFO EchoLIve werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2016 16:29:41] "GET /web/content/245-26ead44/web.assets_common.0.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-08-09 16:29:41,115 5512 INFO EchoLIve werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2016 16:29:41] "GET /web/content/248-fe36041/web.assets_backend.1.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-08-09 16:29:41,131 5512 INFO EchoLIve werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2016 16:29:41] "GET /web/content/247-fe36041/web.assets_backend.0.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-08-09 16:29:41,194 5512 INFO EchoLIve werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2016 16:29:41] "GET /web/content/246-26ead44/web.assets_common.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-08-09 16:29:41,319 5512 INFO EchoLIve werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2016 16:29:41] "GET /web/content/249-fe36041/web.assets_backend.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here are my openerp-server configuration. I tried both in windows and linux.

```
[options]
addons_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20160401\server\openerp\addons,
admin_passwd = admin
bin_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20160401\thirdparty
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A.\Odoo
db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = openpgpwd
db_port = 5432
db_template = template1
db_user = openpg
dbfilter = .*
debug_mode = False
demo = {}
dev_mode = False
email_from = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
import_partial = 
limit_memory_hard = None
limit_memory_soft = None
limit_request = None
limit_time_cpu = None
limit_time_real = None
list_db = True
log_db = False
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20160401\server\openerp-server.log
logrotate = False
longpolling_port = 8072
max_cron_threads = 2
osv_memory_age_limit = 1.0
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20160401\PostgreSQL\bin
pidfile = None
proxy_mode = False
reportgz = False
server_wide_modules = None
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_commit = False
test_enable = False
test_file = False
test_report_directory = False
translate_modules = ['all']
unaccent = False
without_demo = False
workers = None
xmlrpc = True
xmlrpc_interface = 
xmlrpc_port = 8069
```

as well here are the postgres configuration file.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432 
max_connections = 100           
shared_buffers = 128MB      
work_mem = 8MB  
log_destination = 'stderr'      
logging_collector = on      
log_line_prefix = '%t '
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
```

Comment: are u running odoo in cloud server?

Comment: No at local server

Comment: see this link https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/11932

Comment: Is your disk space almost full?

Comment: I have enough disk space only 20gb is acquired